# Synchronize CSS Transition with User Scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions, onscroll

I'm trying to synchronize my css transition with user scroll, so the css transition will run as long as user scrolling the page. To make it clear, i'm trying to do something similar to what [Apple MacBook](http://www.apple.com/macbook/) and [Google Drive](https://www.google.com/drive/) (Heading part) have done.

I know that, there are bunch of plugin out there to do this but i really would like to know the fundamental of it so i have a better understanding.

my current code is below or in [Codepen](http://codepen.io/maddock/pen/YwQvLK). It works but i don't think this is the best way to do it. Thanks in advanced for your help.

```js
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var yScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    var yFixed = (yScroll / 100);

    $("#logger").append(yScroll + " | ");

    //HTML5 Start
    var opacity1 = Math.round((1 - yFixed) * 100) / 100;
    var topOff1 = 0 - yScroll;
    if (opacity1 <= 0) {
      opacity1 = 0;
      topOff1 = -35;
    }
    $(".html5").css({
      "opacity": opacity1,
      "margin-top": topOff1 + "px"
    });

    //CSS3 Start
    var opacity2 = yFixed;
    var topOff2 = 70 - yFixed;
    if (yScroll < 120) {
      opacity2 = 0;
      topOff2 = 70;
    }
    if (opacity2 >= 1) {
      opacity2 = 1;
      topOff2 = 70 - topOff2;
    }
    $(".css3").css({
      "opacity": opacity2,
      "margin-top": topOff2 + "px"
    });

  });
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #9932CC;
}
h1 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 28px;
}
.container {
  margin: 100px auto;
  text-align: center;
  height: 800px;
}
.html5 {
  margin-top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: margin-top .5s ease, opacity .5s ease;
}
.css3 {
  margin-top: 70px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: margin-top .7s ease, opacity .7s ease;
}
#logger {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 150px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="html5">
    <img src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_128.png" />
    <h1>WELCOME TO HTML5</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="css3">
    <img src="http://s18.postimg.org/5j6iv7r5x/css3_logo_128.png" />
    <h1>LET START USING CSS3</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- <div id="logger"></div> -->
```